# Lost sfGuard Admin Password - Need to reset

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I've inherited a Symfony project (which I actually worked on a while ago) and need to reset the password to login to the back-end.

I have access to the MySQL database. I've tried concatenating the salt and new password, then hashing this with sha1 (the algorithm it seems to have logged in the DB), but with no luck.

Can anyone offer any assistance as to how I can change the password without logging into the web application?

Thanks, Rich.

Answer (score 7):

as you can see [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/branches/1.3/lib/task/sfGuardChangePasswordTask.class.php#L44)

there is a task already available inside sfGuardPlugin that you can launch in cli

```
./symfony guard:change-password your_username new_password
```

Comment: Was this added in a recent version of sfGuardPlugin? I don't see it in the one I'm using, which was released on July this year. Thanks for the pointed tho

Comment: maybe it's only available in the svn version of the plugin and has not be included in the zip/plugin, i don't rly know as i only use svn.

Comment: I've tried adding this file (it didn't exist in my version either) using juand's answer below, but when running the task on cli, I get warnings (undefined index argv and array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given) from the sfCommandManager - I'm then given a list of symfony commands available.

Comment: @Rich, what version of php are you running?

Comment: @Rich, also, what does it say in your "algorithm" column in the sf_guard_user table? does it say sha1?

Comment: I believe it's 5.2 running on the server. Yes, the algorithm column says sha1 - wondering if there's something 'more wrong' with the site...

Comment: @Pascal suggested that the user may be inactive. e.g. is_active=false.. have you checked that @Rich?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from code more easily..

```
$sf_guard_user = sfGuardUserPeer::retrieveByUsername( 'USERNAME_HERE' );

if( is_null($sf_guard_user) ){
    throw new \Exception( 'Could not find user' );
}

$sf_guard_user->setPassword( $password );
$sf_guard_user->save();

$this->logSection( "Password change for user: ", $sf_guard_user->getUsername() );
```

I use a pake task.

Create a file in project/lib/task and call it setUserPasswordTask.class.php (name must end in "Task")

The class would look something like this:

```
<?php


class setClientPasswordTask extends sfBaseTask {

    /**
    * @see sfTask
    */
    protected function configure() {

        parent::configure();

        $this->addArguments(array(
            new sfCommandArgument( 'username', sfCommandArgument::REQUIRED, 'Username of the user to change', null ),
            new sfCommandArgument( 'password', sfCommandArgument::REQUIRED, 'Password to set', null )
        ));

        $this->addOptions(array(
            new sfCommandOption( 'application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', 'frontend' ),
            new sfCommandOption( 'env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'prod' ),
            new sfCommandOption( 'connection', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The connection name', 'propel' ),
        ));


        $this->namespace = 'guard';

        $this->name = 'set-user-password';

        $this->briefDescription = 'Changes a User\'s password.';

        $this->detailedDescription = 'Changes a User\'s password.';
    }



  /**
   * @see sfTask
   */
    protected function execute( $arguments = array(), $options = array() ) {

        // initialize the database connection
            $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager( $this->configuration );
            $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();     
            $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration( $options['application'], $options['env'], true );

            sfContext::createInstance( $configuration );


        // Change user password 

            $username           =  $arguments['username'];
            $password           =  $arguments['password'];


            $sf_guard_user = sfGuardUserPeer::retrieveByUsername( 'USERNAME_HERE' );

            if( is_null($sf_guard_user) ){
                throw new \Exception( 'Could not find user' );
            }

            $sf_guard_user->setPassword( $password );
            $sf_guard_user->save();

            $this->logSection( "Password changed for user: ", $sf_guard_user->getUsername() );


    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that!

I'll give it a go. Until then, any help with the DB would be great.

Comment: To change it from the db, you can define a salt, say "123" and set the salt field with that value, then calculate the sha1 value of 123 plus the password you want.. e.g. "123password". set the password value to that and your password is now "password"

Comment: You can use this to calculate SHA1 values: http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator

Comment: Juand, this is what I tried already - I still cannot seem to login :(

Comment: @juand maybe this user is inactive (is_active = false)